# Invalid Swift Support use latest GM

Tags: ios, swift

Trying to submit my app to the store, which works when setting Target iOS version to 10.x.  If i set it to 12.x or 13.x I get Invalid Swift Support / The SwiftSupport folder is empty?

```
Embedded Content Contains Swift Code is set to YES
```

I have one swift file that I am using, but it only contains this. I had removed the file as was using Dataservice before, but removed it as not needed. I put it back because of this error.

Dataservice.swift

```
import Foundation

class DataService {
   //nothing
}
```

Used here.

User.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@class DataService;
//@class UpdateService;


@interface User : NSObject
{
    NSString *username;
}

@end
```

Finally, I am submitting to in Xcode as for the Store, NOT adhoc for distribution.

I don't see a Project-Swift.h file in my folder structure on the left. Should one be there or is just generated when sent to the store?

Comment: What does "use latest GM" mean? There is no current GM of Xcode.

Comment: What version of Xcode do you have?

Comment: Version 11.4 (11E146)

Comment: I think the issue is that in Xcode there is no Target-Swift.h file. I read if you create a .swift file in your Objc project Xcode will ask if you want it to make one. It never asked. I do see the Burro-Bridging-Header.h which is for when you want to use ObjC code in a Swift project.

Comment: I renamed the unused swift files from .swift to .h and removed any reference to header files (-swift.h and -bridge-header.h) in the build settings. This didn't work. But I submitted to the store again this time with the "Include bitcode for iOS content" checked and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I renamed the unused swift files from .swift to .h and removed any reference to header files (-swift.h and -bridge-header.h) in the build settings. This didn't work. But I submitted to the store again this time with the "Include bitcode for iOS content" checked and it worked.